# Magento 2 static deploy throws 'Unable to unserialize value' error - what does it mean and how to resolve it?

Tags: magento, magento2

When I Run `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` it gives me an error that I don't understand. I created a custom theme with the help of `devdocs` but still gives me an error.

If you need to review any of my custom files please let me know.

[image: Error message]

Comment: what's the path to the file in the errpr?